# How to handling bad request in REST service

Tags: java, rest, http-status-codes

I have a rest service that receives an object like this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date insertDate;
    //getter setter
}
```

My controller has a saveItem method of this type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/item", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public Object saveItem(@RequestBody(required = false) Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
 //code..
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

when an incorrect date format arrives, an error is generated that is not handled by me because it does not enter the if. Why does this happen? How should it be managed?
The problem occurred even without the @JsonFormat annotation

Comment: To change the data type to String which completes capture the value as it is coming from JSON payload. Using Date and other data types were converting the value to other data types.

Comment: Please make sure your entire question is in English.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that there were untranslated parts

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using spring boot. You can use ControllerAdvice in order to define response in case of exceptions. You can define multiple handlers as multiple methods annotated with ExceptionHandler.

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(InvalidArgumentException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto<Object>> handleException(Exception exception) {
    log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(<someBody>, HttpStatus. BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto<Object>> handleException2(Exception exception) {
    log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(<someBody>, HttpStatus. INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Comment: After defining this controller, how should I use it in my saveItem method?

Comment: You can not use it in saveItem method.

Comment: how does my method know it has to throw the exceptions defined in the RestControllerAdvice?

Comment: ResponseEntity does not return the error class I created. I also tried to make it print a simple string but the json is always empty. why?otherwise it works